# Ruby on Rails: Best way to handle repeated error checking without goto?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, goto

In languages that have goto, I like to create an error block at the end of a function (after return) and then when I do error checking within the function, I can just be concise and goto the error handler within each check. As I understand it, this is the one valid use of goto that isn't considered bad practice.

Example in pseudocode:

```
 def example
   if (x) goto error
   do something
   if (y) goto error
   do something
   If (z) goto error
   do something
   return
  label 'error'
   log "error occurred"
   begin
     redirect_to :back
   rescue
     redirect_to root_url
   end
   return;
 end
```

As you can see, in this case, my error block is as long as the function itself, and repeating it 3 times would double the size of my code, and not be very DRY. However, it seems that Ruby doesn't support goto, or at least if it does, as best as I can tell from looking on Google, it's some sort of possibly joke library labeled evil.

**Therefore, what are people doing in Ruby in order to handle repeated error checking where the same result should occur in each error?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Callbacks

You should transfer many of these errors into your models, using [Callbacks](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html). These apply to errors that are relevant to actions that involve records in your database, i.e. checking whether a data input is appropriate.

### Filters

Use before_filters and after_filters to check for errors, especially when you need to perform these checks on multiple controller actions. An example:

```
before_filter :check_errors

def example
   regular code...
end

private
  def check_errors
    error checking...
  end
```

### Case statements

Use [Case statements](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/The_Ruby_case_Statement) to improve your `if` statements, particularly when you have multiple checks involved.

### Prioritizing the above

Use callbacks in your models whenever you can and definitely whenever data saving/updating/validation is involved.

Use `before_filters` whenever the code is to be reused across multiple actions (and in my opinion, always whenever you have involved error checking like this).

If you need these checks to occur only once, in this controller action alone, that do not involve records being changed, simply rewrite your code in a valid case statement (but my recommendation would still be to transfer to a before_filter).

Comment: So let me give you a somewhat more concrete scenario that I'm actually dealing with, and tell me what you think. My controller method is first loading Model1, and if no Model1, then error. It then reads Model1 and uses information from that to load Model2, and if no Model2, then error. Then Model3 is loaded, which is used to check security permissions by the User on Model2, and if not present then error. Finally, both Model1 and Model2 are used in the view. It strikes me as very odd to be loading instance variables in a before_filter.

Comment: @WilliamJones - 1) Is it necessary that you get a different error in case of Model1 vs Model2 vs Model3 failure? 2) There's nothing wrong with loading these models in the before_filter, especially for DRY purposes if you want to do this in multiple actions. 3) If you're dealing with security, you may like to check out a lightweight permissions solution like CanCan. All these layers of checks are going to slow down your rendering.

Comment: Nothing at all wrong with setting instance variables in filters.  In fact some common patterns involve using before_filters to setup common model loading, to DRY up the code.

Comment: Agree about setting instance variables in before filters… remember that instance in a controllers case refers to the singular request lifecycle and whose state results in an HTTP response. @sscirrus points out that validation ensures your database has integrity (else an _validation error_ would have been raised when something could be done about it and Model1 wouldn't have come to be). Given this and your options regarding outcome won't you really just be choosing between 404 or 500? (Likely a gross oversimplification of your issue, for which I apologize)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a little secret: Exceptions are basically glorified gotos. Also, ruby has a catch/throw syntax, see: http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/tut_exceptions.html

In your case, ask, is it really an *error* or just an undesirable condition.  An error to me is when a belongs_to references a record that doesn't exist, but having an empty belongs_to isn't.  This changes from situation to situation.

Looking at your comment above, I think I would be more inclined to add some private methods that set the instance variables and return true of false, and chain them together:

```
if load_model1 && load_model2 && load_model3
  ... do regular page view
else
  #render error page, use  @load_error
end

private
  def load_model1
     @model1 = ....
     if @model1.blank?  # or nil? or whatever error condition
        @load_error="model 1 failed
        return false
     else
        return true
     end
  end

  def load_model2
    ...
  end

  def load_model3
     ...
  end
```